# Optimize parsing of number for currency conversion

Tags: java, parsing, floating-point, i18n, finance

I have written this working block, but is it optimized? I am getting currency in this format: 1.234,25.

```
public static String convertCurrency(String value, String exchangeCurrencyId)
{
    java.text.NumberFormat format = null;
    value = value.replaceAll("\\.", ",");
    char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
    chars[value.lastIndexOf(',')] = '.';
    value = new String(chars);
    value = value.replaceAll(",", "");
    Double price = Double.valueOf(value);
    price = price * (50); //exchange rate

    return price.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you replace `\\.` by `,`, change last `,` and replace all `,` by empty string? Why you can't immediately replace `.` by empty string and after that replace `,` by `.` if it exists?

Comment: You have a couple of larger problems; `Double` (and floating point in general) does _not_ store exact amounts like people expect - ie, `.1` can't be represented (only something really close).  This can lead to surprising results, which tends to make people itchy when it involves money.  You're also storing the amount in a string, which means you have to convert it each time.  For money, you want to use something based off/backed by `BigDecimal`, so you get the values you're expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you tried to use `NumberFormat` but gave up on the idea.  You should take advantage of it — after all, that's what the standard library is there for.

Furthermore, I would split the parsing and the currency conversion into two separate functions.

You should avoid "stringly typed" variables.  Once you parse the string into a number, hang on to the number, not the string.  Convert back into string form as late as possible, just for presentation purposes.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CR38317 {
    public static BigDecimal parseCurrency(String value) throws ParseException {
        // Pick a suitable locale.  GERMANY, for example, uses the 1.234,56 format.
        // You could call .getCurrencyInstance() instead, but then it will
        // require the value to contain the correct currency symbol at a
        // specific position.
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

        // By default, fmt.parse() returns a Number that is a Double.
        // However, some decimals, such as 0.10, cannot be represented
        // exactly in floating point, so it is considered best practice to
        // use BigDecimal for storing monetary values.
        ((DecimalFormat)fmt).setParseBigDecimal(true);

        return (BigDecimal)fmt.parse(value);
    }

    public static BigDecimal convertCurrency(BigDecimal inValue, String inCurrency, String outCurrency) {
        // TODO: Derive the conversion rate from the currencies
        return inValue.multiply(new BigDecimal(50));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        BigDecimal in = parseCurrency("1.234,56");
        BigDecimal out = convertCurrency(in, "EUR", "INR");
        System.out.println("In = " + in);
        System.out.println("Out = " + out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It was in my mind to use NumberFormat. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This code has various issues. Here is what I understand your code does:

> The code takes a formatted number which consists of digits, separators (commas or periods). The last separator is used as the decimal separator, all other separators are deleted.
>
> Then it multiplies the number with some exchange rate, and returns that as a string.

The issues with your code are:

- `format` is not used.
- `exchangeCurrencyID` is not used.
- The exchange rate is hard-coded
- You use regexes for simple transliterations
- Your code obfuscates the intent.
- Your method does multiple unrelated things:

  1. Sanitizing and parsing the number string
  2. Applying exchange rate conversion
     These separate responsibilities should be performed by two separate methods.

If we wish to avoid using regexes for a task that does not need them, we could write something like this:

```
StringBuilder sanitized = new StringBuilder();
boolean decimalSeparatorFound = false;
char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (chars[i] == ',' || chars[i] == '.') {
        if (decimalSeparatorFound) continue;  // skip this char
        decimalSeparatorFound = true;
        sanitized.append('.');
    } else {
        sanitized.append(chars[i]);
    }
}
double price = Double.valueOf(sanitized.reverse().toString());

...
```

Comment: it is throwing `NumberFormatException` as it appends comma `,`. Here comma needs to be replaced with dot `.`.

Comment: I have added some code after edit. any suggestion over this

Comment: @eatSleepCode No, that doesn't count: You just copied out the part of your code with least criticism. And you didn't manage without a loop, you just hid it behind a call to `replaceAll`. If you want to optimize for performance, you shouldn't use regexes if they aren't needed.

Comment: You could remove the regexes and not use a `for` loop by simply changing the call to `String.replaceAll()` to `String.replace()` which takes a char argument instead of a regex String.